# AS3, Flash - Disable all buttons? Except one?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Is it possible somehow to make a function which will disable all buttons?
And like make grey alpha overlay over the whole flash file?

But only one movie clip should not be overlayed, and one button should not be disabled.

Can this be done some easy way, or do I have to make a code to disable all single button?

Comment: Yes/No.  An easy way to possibly do it is intercept the mouse event(s) on the capture phase and stop propogation if the the target isn't a descendant of your lone allowed movie clip.   The visual aspect depends largely on how you've setup your display hierarchy.  creating a gray overlay is easy enough.   What does your display structure look like?  Are you using the flash IDE and doing things on the timeline, or using a document class file and doing things in custom class files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create an overlay movie clip that would intercept the clicks.
2. addChild(overlay) the overlay.
3. addChild(button) the button you want over the overlay.

addChild moves whatever object to the topmost tier of the movie clip you are adding it to.  So passing the gray overlay to addChild last draws it over all your objects on the screen.  Then calling it with the button you want as a parameter makes it show up over the gray overlay since it is the last object you passed addChild().